# Has the Catholic Church ever thought of replacing the prayer "Tower of ivory, pray for us" in the Litany of Loreto?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, tradition

The Litany of Loreto to Our Lady contains a prayer: "Tower of ivory, pray for us". Of course, this prayer was written at a time when ivory was in abundance, and there was no prohibition against its use in arts. But in today's context when most nations have prohibited the use of ivory with a view to promoting the awareness of protection of the environment, it is high time that the Church took a serious view on retention of the said prayer in the Litany, unless there are figurative implications to the prayer. My question therefore is: Has the Catholic Church ever thought of replacing the prayer ***"Tower of ivory, pray for us"*** in the Litany of Loreto?

Comment: " it is high time that the Church took a serious view on retention of the said prayer in the Litany," That's a very disputable point. Does anyone seriously think that using "tower of ivory" in a prayer encourages the ivory trade? Hopefully not. "unless there are figurative implications to the prayer" There are. No one thinks Mary is a literal tower of ivory nor a gate (of heaven) nor a mirror (of justice).

Comment: **“It is high time that the Church took a serious view on retention of the said prayer in the Litany,”** No one should speak of Our Lady’s honour thus! You should show more research into your questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Has the Catholic Church ever thought of replacing the prayer “Tower of ivory, pray for us” in the Litany of Loreto?**

The short answer is **no**.

There is no need to replace or even suppress the invocation ***“Tower of ivory, Pray for us”*** from the [Litany of the Blessed Virgin Mary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litany_of_the_Blessed_Virgin_Mary)also known as the Litany of Loreto (Litaniae lauretanae).

Besides the image of an ivory tower is used in the Bible in the Song of Solomon to describe a woman’s purity.

> [**Ivory tower**](https://grammarist.com/idiom/ivory-tower/)
>
> Ivory tower means a place where one may exist, isolated from the cares of the real world and everyday life. Academics, philosophers and artists are sometimes accused of living in ivory towers, meaning that their ways of thinking are not practical in real-world situations. **The image of an *ivory tower* is used in the Bible in the *Song of Solomon* to describe a woman’s purity.** The modern meaning of the term ivory tower first appears in France in the 1830s as tour d’ivoire to mean an impractical dreamer. The phrase migrated into the English language fifty years later, the meaning possibly reinforced by the appearance of the Hawksmoor Towers at Oxford University’s All Souls’ College which were probably close to an ivory color when the term ivory tower entered the English language. The phrase is sometimes rendered capitalized as in Ivory Tower, but most dictionaries prefer the lowercase form.